# How do you position elements in CSS with margin without it affecting anything else

Tags: html, css

I am trying to move this form but it keeps 'hitting' the h3 tag and the button. I want to move them around without them interfering with one another.

I am talking about the gray panel:
[image: gray panel]

Even when resizing the window, they interact and push one another.
I have tried using margin and padding, but that doesn't seem to work.

```css
.section-3 {
  position: relative;
  background-color: white;
  height: 600px;
  top: 959px;
  text-align: center;
}

.join-btn {
  height: 45px;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-transform: uppercase;

  text-align: center;

  border-radius: 2px;
  padding: 9px 20px 7px;
  color: #373f3d;
  border: 2px solid rgba(55, 63, 61, 0.2);
}

.section-3 .heading_section_3 {
  font-size: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 70%;
}

.description {
  position: absolute;
  color: #6e6e6e;
  padding-left: 200px;
  padding-right: 200px;
}

.join-right-side {
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: #c9c8c8;
  position: absolute;
  height: 300px;
  padding: 30px;
  margin-left: 50%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 50%;
}

.Join-left-side {
  overflow: auto;
  position: absolute;
  height: 300px;
  padding: 30px;
  background-color: #f5f5f1;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 50%;
}

.text-join-left {
  color: black;
  text-align: center;

  padding-left: 200px;
  padding-right: 200px;
}
.form {
  height: fit-content;
  overflow: hidden;
}

input[type="email"] {
  border-color: black;
  border-width: 2px;
  background-color: #c9c8c8;
  box-sizing: border-box;

  list-style: none;
  direction: ltr;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 200px 200px 0px 0px;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  appearance: none;
  background: none;
  border: none;
  color: #373f3d;
  font-family: GT Pressura Mono, Roboto Mono, monospace;
  font-size: 28px;
  line-height: 28px;
  font-weight: 400;
}
```

```html
<div class="section-3">
  <div class="join-right-side">
    <div class="join-btn">Join</div>
    <h3 class="text-join-left">Sign up and get 10% off your first purchase.</h3>
    <form class="form" action="/">
      <input
        class="input"
        placeholder="Your email address..."
        type="email"
        name="EMAIL"
      />
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="join-left-side">
    <h2 class="heading_section_3">Swallowtail Tea</h2>
    <h3 class="description">
      Swallowtail Tea is a Virginia-based tea company sourcing only the highest
      quality tea, herbs, and spices from around the world.
    </h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

I think it could be linked to the way I'm accessing the div classes, or to the structure of the div's.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read about the [best way to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to provide a **minimal**, **reproducible** example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Sharing your HTML and CSS code as a [stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) will also make it a lot easier for the community to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

CSS

```
.section-3 {
       display:flex;
       justify-content: space-between;
}
.join-left-side , .join-right-side {
    width : 50%;
    height: 300px;
 }
 
 .section-3 {
   position: relative;
   background-color: white;
   height: 600px;
   top: 959px;
   text-align: center;
}

.join-btn {
   height: 45px;
   font-size: 16px;
   text-transform: uppercase;

   text-align: center;

   border-radius: 2px;
   padding: 9px 20px 7px;
   color: #373f3d;
   border: 2px solid rgba(55, 63, 61, .2);


}

.section-3 .heading_section_3 {
   font-size: 20px;
  

}

.description {
   color: #6e6e6e;


}

.join-right-side {
   background-color: #c9c8c8;
   height: 300px;
   padding: 30px;
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
   justify-content: center;
   width: 50%;
}

.join-left-side {
   align-items: center;
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
   justify-content: center;
}
 
.form{
   height: fit-content;
   overflow: hidden;
   
}

input[type=email] {
   
    border-color: black;
   border-width: 2px;
   background-color: #c9c8c8;
   box-sizing: border-box;
   


   list-style: none;
   direction: ltr;
   box-sizing: border-box;
   padding: 0;
   margin: 200px 200px 0px 0px;
   display: block;
   width: 100%;
   appearance: none;
   background: none;
   border: none;
   color: #373f3d;
   font-family: GT Pressura Mono,Roboto Mono,monospace;
   font-size: 28px;
   line-height: 28px;
   font-weight: 400;

}
```

HTML

```
<div class="section-3">

  <div class="join-left-side">
    <h2 class="heading_section_3">Swallowtail Tea</h2>
    <h3 class="description">
      Swallowtail Tea is a Virginia-based tea company sourcing only the highest
      quality tea, herbs, and spices from around the world.
    </h3>
  </div>
  <div class="join-right-side">
    <div class="join-btn">Join</div>
    <h3 class="text-join-left">Sign up and get 10% off your first purchase.</h3>
    <form class="form" action="/">
      <input
        class="input"
        placeholder="Your email address..."
        type="email"
        name="EMAIL"
      />
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```